# Create NEST search request for Elasticsearch with ignore_unavailable set to true?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to create a NEST search request for elasticsearch and ignore index not exists errors.  I can do this using sense by appending ?ignore_unavailable=true to the search request but can't find a way to set this with NEST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var searchResult = this._client.Search<ElasticsearchProject>(s => s
    .IgnoreUnavailable()
    .MatchAll()
);
```